# Why does Z3 keeps a variable at the same value even if it is specified not to do that

Tags: z3, solver, smt

I am encountering a problem in Z3 for which I can't seem to find where it originates from and how to fix it. My goal that for a given certain iteration (for-loop) that is composed of an `if-then-else` statement at each step; is it possible to achieve a given value k after the loop has finished. This is done without knowing the structure of `if`. In other words, i need to check every possible mapping of the function (true or false) for each step. More precisely in smt2 format:

```
(declare-fun a(Int) Int)
(declare-fun b(Int) Int)
(assert (= 1 (a 0)))
(assert (= 1 (b 0)))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 1) (+ (a 0) (* 2 (b 0)))) (= (b 1) (+ 1 (b 0)))) (and (= (b 1) (+ (a 0) (b 0))) (= (a 1) (+ (b 0) 1)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 2) (+ (a 1) (* 2 (b 1)))) (= (b 2) (+ 2 (b 1)))) (and (= (b 2) (+ (a 1) (b 1))) (= (a 2) (+ (b 1) 2)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 3) (+ (a 2) (* 2 (b 2)))) (= (b 3) (+ 3 (b 2)))) (and (= (b 3) (+ (a 2) (b 2))) (= (a 3) (+ (b 2) 3)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 4) (+ (a 3) (* 2 (b 3)))) (= (b 4) (+ 4 (b 3)))) (and (= (b 4) (+ (a 3) (b 3))) (= (a 4) (+ (b 3) 4)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 5) (+ (a 4) (* 2 (b 4)))) (= (b 5) (+ 5 (b 4)))) (and (= (b 5) (+ (a 4) (b 4))) (= (a 5) (+ (b 4) 5)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 6) (+ (a 5) (* 2 (b 5)))) (= (b 6) (+ 6 (b 5)))) (and (= (b 6) (+ (a 5) (b 5))) (= (a 6) (+ (b 5) 6)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 7) (+ (a 6) (* 2 (b 6)))) (= (b 7) (+ 7 (b 6)))) (and (= (b 7) (+ (a 6) (b 6))) (= (a 7) (+ (b 6) 7)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 8) (+ (a 7) (* 2 (b 7)))) (= (b 8) (+ 8 (b 7)))) (and (= (b 8) (+ (a 7) (b 7))) (= (a 8) (+ (b 7) 8)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 9) (+ (a 8) (* 2 (b 8)))) (= (b 9) (+ 9 (b 8)))) (and (= (b 9) (+ (a 8) (b 8))) (= (a 9) (+ (b 8) 9)))))
(assert (xor (and ( = (a 10) (+ (a 9) (* 2 (b 9)))) (= (b 10) (+ 10 (b 9)))) (and (= (b 10) (+ (a 9) (b 9))) (= (a 10) (+ (b 9) 10)))))
(assert (= (b 10) 461))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

The `xor` operator is used to check if the statement for `then` holds or the statement in `else` holds, **but not both**. So the the variable `a` or `b` is bounded to follow only one valid path. Somehow the values sometimes don't seem to obey this rule or they do not change, and I am unable to tell why is this happening. As for example take this output for `a`, for the step `2` and `3` the value doesn't change, which should not be possible:

```
 (define-fun a ((x!0 Int)) Int
    (ite (= x!0 0) 1
    (ite (= x!0 1) 3
    (ite (= x!0 2) 7 <--- should not be possible but keeps happening
    (ite (= x!0 3) 7 <---
    (ite (= x!0 4) 29
    [...]
```

I don't know if i either am encountering a bug or my logic involved in the solution for this problem is flawed. I tried to use Bounded Model Checking. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: It's really difficult to follow your encoding. Can you post a simpler example? (For instance, unroll only twice, and show the original program--even in pseudo-code, and make sure the model presented is indeed not valid. I've a feeling it's a perfectly valid model that you're getting, it just is the case that what you modeled is not what you intended.)

Comment: I tried to explain the code as simple as possible without the need of displaying the pseudocode, but you are right and I appriciate your feedback. I will keep this in mind for questions that I might make in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue:** the problem is either in your understanding of how the loop should behave, or in the encoding of the formula implementing the logic of the loop. Since you didn't provide the original pseudo-code, I cannot guess any further.

---

Let's take this:

```
(assert (xor
            (and
                (= (a 1) (+ (a 0) (* 2 (b 0))))
                (= (b 1) (+ 1 (b 0)))
             )
            (and
                (= (b 1) (+ (a 0) (b 0)))
                (= (a 1) (+ (b 0) 1))
             )
         )
 )
```

The expression that is being unrolled is:

```
   (                  -- #then-branch
        a' := a + 2 * b
            /\
        b' := K + b
   )
xor
   (                  -- #else-branch
        a' = K + b
            /\
        b' = a + b
   )
```

where `K` depends on the current iteration, starting with `1`.

---

***Q:*** is the solution provided by the SMT solver feasible? **YES!**
*(the portion you have shared with us..)*

```
a_0 := 1
b_0 := 1

-- execute #then-branch (K = 1)

a_1 := a_0 + 2 * b_0 = 1 + 2 * 1 = 3
b_1 := K + b_0       = 1 + 1     = 2

-- execute #then-branch (K = 2)

a_2 := a_1 + 2 * b_1 = 3 + 2 * 2 = 7
b_2 := K + b_1       = 2 + 2     = 4

-- execute #else-branch (K = 3)

a_3 := K + b_2   = 3 + 4 = 7 
b_3 := a_2 + b_2 = 7 + 4 = 11

-- execute #then-branch (K = 4)

a_4 := a_3 + 2 * b_3 = 7 + 2 * 11 = 29
b_4 := K + b_3       = 4 + 11     = 15

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the issue and it was a logical error in my solution. Furthermore, if you are interested I can post the correct solution for my problem. If there is no further request, I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: I used ``ite`` instead of ``xor`` with some further configuration to make it work

Comment: @user108692 In case you desire to post your own answer, please include inside your post the missing details from the question (e.g. the loop code).